# asp .net app .ts files won't bundle into js file

Tags: typescript, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I'm working as a coop student for a company that has an asp .net MVC app.  They introduced typescript files to their project not too long ago.  I found out while making style/css changes that any changes I made to typescript files were not being reflected in the actual views/on the page because I was missing the js bundle file.  I was given that file.

Now, however, unless I am directly editing that bundle file, changes to typescript files are not being included in that bundle file.

I have compared my BundleConfig.cs and tsconfig.json files to ones given to me by the lead developer, and they are the same.  I have checked csproj file for this configuration `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>false</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` from this stackoverflowarticle: [JavaScript file not updated after typescript file change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180873/javascript-file-not-updated-after-typescript-file-change) - but it's from 2017 and I don't think it exists anymore?

If anyone could give me any help I would really appreciate it.